# Finding the domain of $[\log_{10}(\frac{5x - x^2}{4})]^{1/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The solution given by the book is:

[image: book]

I think this is wrong. My solution is:

$\frac{5x - x^2}{4}$ $\ge$ $1$

$5x - x^2$ $\ge$ $4$

$5x - x^2 - 4$ $\ge$ $0$

$(-1)(x-1)(x-4)$ $\ge$ $0$

**or**

$(x-1)(x-4)$ $\le$ $0$

**not**

$(x-1)(x-4)$ $\ge$ $0$

Thus,

Domain of $x$ $\in$ $[1,4]$

Comment: yes you are correct. Book solution seems wrong.